# show all invariant subspaces are of the form

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

here u_L is minimal polynomial

there's a theorem that says:

if V = C_x then deg of min poly = dim V.

Answer (score 0):

In what follows, $V=[v]$ is cyclic. We use that, in general

> *Lemma* Let $w \in V$ be nonzero. If $ \mu_w=fg$ with $f$ monic, then $\mu_{f(T)w}=g$

First

> *Claim 1* Suppose that $f\mid \mu_T$ is a monic divisor, say $\mu_T=fg$. Then $\ker f(T)=[g(T)v]$ and $\mu_{\ker f(T)}=f$.

*Proof* Write $\mu_T=fg$. Since $f(T)g(T)v=0$, we have that $[g(T)v]\subseteq \ker f(T)$. Now, $\dim [g(T)v]=\deg \mu_{g(T)v}=\deg f$ and similarily $\dim[f(T)v]=\deg g$. It follows that $$\begin{align}\dim \ker f(T)&=\dim V-\dim f(T)V\\&=\deg \mu_T-\dim f(T)[v]\\&=\deg \mu_T-\dim [f(T)v]\\&=\deg \mu_T-\deg g\\&=\deg f=\dim [g(T)v]\end{align}$$

Thus $\ker f(T)=[g(T)v]$. Finally, we see $m_{\ker f(T)}=m_{g(T)v}=m_v/g=f$.

> *Claim 2* If $W$ is an invariant subspace, is of the form $\ker f(T)$ for some monic divisor of $\mu_f$.

*Proof* We know there exists $w\in W$ such that $\mu_{T\mid W}$.  Write $\mu_T=\mu_{T\mid W}f$. Using the first claim, $[w]\subseteq W\subseteq \ker \mu_{T\mid W}(T)=\ker m_w(T)=[f(T)v]$. Since $m_{f(T)v}=m_{T\mid W}$, we have $\dim [f(T)v]=\deg m_{f(T)v}=\deg \mu_{T\mid W}=\deg m_w=[w]$, so $W=[f(T)v]$.

> *Corollary* Every invariant subspace is cyclic.